# Firestore PHP - get one field from document

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a firestore that looks like this

[image]

and I want to be able to get just one value from a document, like getting the "uid" from the highlighted document, my php code looks like this:

```
<?php

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    //putenv('upheld-pursuit-274606-237ac40b2662.json');
    use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

    class Firestore
    {
        protected $db;
        protected $name;
        public function __construct(string $collection)
        {
            $this->db = new FirestoreClient([
                'keyFilePath' => 'upheld-pursuit-274606-237ac40b2662.json',
                'projectId' => 'upheld-pursuit-274606'
            ]);

            $this->name = $collection;
        }


        public function getWhere(string $field, string $operator, $value)
        {
            $arr = [];
            $query = $this->db->collection($this->name)->where($field, $operator, $value)->documents()->rows();
            if(!empty($query)){
                foreach ($query as $q){
                    $arr[] = $q->data();
                }
            }
            return $arr;
        }

        public function get(string $field)
        {
            $arr = [];
            $query = $this->db->collection($this->name)->document($field)();
            if(!empty($query)){
                /*foreach ($query as $q){
                    $arr[] = $q->data();
                }*/
                throw new Exception('Document does not exist!');
            }
            return $query;
        }

    }
?>
```

and the code calling it looks like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

require("connect.php");
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'Firestore.php';

$fs = new Firestore('users');
$tfs = new Firestore('tutors');


    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['name']);

    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['pass']);

    $password = md5($password);

    $data = array();

    print_r($fs->get('1WINXTQdshhn4jLfhMWWaZNNdL32'));
```

I want to be able to retrieve just one field from a document in case I need for certain if statements or other conditional statements and for checking purposes

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can only do this with NodeJS package for Cloud Firestore.
In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49497265/13128009) there's  a link to [the doc for firestore select](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/#select) which does this.

Answer (score 0):

Just as any of the other Client Libraries, the PHP `google/cloud-firestore` has the [select method](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.155.1/firestore/query?method=select), which allows you to select the fields that you want to be retrieved.

I recommend checking the `simple_queries.php` [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/6d8ba787ea4e830c29962ba8ea064d38bd826260/firestore/src/simple_queries.php), if you need further examples on how to set up these queries.